# Unbounded Finity?

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

Consider the successor of the largest finite ordinal that will ever be considered alone. But then it wasn't the largest finite ordinal that will ever be considered alone. How do we get around this paradox? The largest finite ordinal that will ever be considered alone does exist, and yet we can consider its successor.

Comment: Consider the oldest brother of a leprechaun.

Comment: @vadim123 I tried that, but I still can't find the pot of gold.

Comment: @vadim123 There are no brothers of leprechauns. I can't tell if that is only a joke, or if there is some hidden mathematical/logical meaning.(Jokes are not unwelcome)

Comment: The number of largest finite ordinals is equal to the number of leprechauns. What does "be considered by itself" mean exactly?

Comment: @sea turtles :no, there really is 1 and only 1 largest finite ordinal that we will consider by itself.

Comment: Can you explain what "consider by itself" means? Is that a technical phrase in set theory I haven't seen? (I am not a set theorist, so I wouldn't know.)

Comment: @seaturtles : Yes, you are considering that number and no other. Its not supposed to be a technical term, its supposed to be plain English.

Comment: Another (more clear?) formulation is {The largest finite ordinal we will ever put in curly brackets by itself +1}. If you say there is no largest finite ordinal we will ever put in curly brackets by itself, it follows immediately that we have never put a finite ordinal in curly brackets, a demonstrable falsehood.

Comment: The "largest ordinal that we'll ever consider" is circularly defined in terms of itself. There is a non-set-theoretic way to phrase the paradox. I would say, "let $x$ be the integer value which is one greater than the largest integer value referred to in this comment."

Comment: @vadim123 : I see where my original phrasing was unclear (ordinals do not consider things as far as I know, if that is what you were getting at)

Comment: @seaturtles: The difference is that the largest finite ordinal I will ever consider must exist by the well ordering principle. It either exists or I have never considered an ordinal. In your statement, you never refer to an integer value. I have considered ordinals.

Comment: The set of finite ordinals you will have ever considered is still a set that you are in the process of making. If you are considering the successor of the maximum element of this still-being-created set, you are circularly defining an element of this set in terms of the set itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This apparent paradox has nothing to do with ordinals, or metalanguage.  It is a time travel/omniscience paradox.  Let's strip away the unnecessary bits.

How many words will the longest sentence I personally will say tomorrow be?  Maybe I predict seven, but that doesn't stop me from saying a sentence with eight words.  No matter my prediction, I can break it.

You will note that the difficulty disappears if the time travel is taken away.  If we ask about the largest ordinal that has *previously* been considered, that is a unique number (that periodically increases with time).

Comment: I think this is the best answer. While in your example there is some bound (speaking more words takes more time) and in mine there isn't, my structure seems to just exacerbate the same pathology. Now for me to draw my philosophical conclusions...

Answer (score 8):

This is essentially [Jules Richard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox). You define an ordinal in a language and then talk about its consequences in the metalanguage. But it's not problematic in the original language and doesn't have the desired property in the metalanguage.

Basically, the difficulty comes from the imprecision of natural language ("the largest finite ordinal that will ever be considered by itself") and its translation into a formal language where it can be unambiguously defined.

Comment: And just to add to this good answer: if we can be loose about what it means to refer to a number (or "consider" it), then all numbers are referred to in $\forall$ statements.  Such as $\forall_x . \exists s(x)$. So there is no largest. But if we try to be specific about what is meant, we have to quickly address whether the statement itself is such a reference and make a choice as to the resolution.  There is certainly a largest number that will ever be written out in... (pick a format, like base 10).  The statement doesn't refer to that number because "consider successor" isn't writing out.

Comment: I can see how this means in math we have to limit ourselves and use formal languages if we are to avoid such paradox. What I don't understand is that my statement is really ambiguous: there really IS a largest finite ordinal we will ever consider by itself (thus avoiding the universal quantifier). That is, we can avoid the paradox but I haven't been convinced that it isn't actually a paradox.

Comment: @Jacob: Peano arithmetic tells us that "0" is a natural number, and that if $x$ and $y$ are both natural numbers, then $x+y$ is a natural number. However, nothing in Peano's axioms guarantees "The largest natural number humans will ever consider alone" is a natural number. Induction cannot prove "there is a largest number that humans will consider alone" because "humans will consider X alone" is not a predicate you can construct in the natural numbers.

Comment: We can even give a model: one might look at nonstandard analysis, and interpret "numbers that humans will consider alone" to be the standard numbers. And in this nonstandard model, there exist integers larger than every integer humans will consider alone; yet there is no largest number that humans will consider alone.